# How to scroll to next div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm making a website with a lot of Divs that take 100% height. 
And I want to make a button so when it's clicked to smoothly scroll to next div.
I've coded something so when its clicked, it scrolls to specific div.

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".p2").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.p1{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
.p2{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #E91E63;
}
.p3{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #01579B;
}

.admin{
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p1">
  
</div>
<div class="p2">
  
</div>
<div class="p3">
  
</div>

<div class="admin">
  
  <button class="next">NEXT</button>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make this work you need to identify the currently displayed `div`. For that you can apply a class to the element which is currently shown. Then you can use `next()` to traverse through them all.

Also note in the below example the addition of a common class on all elements, `.p`, in order to DRY up the CSS and make DOM traversal easier.

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
  var $target = $('.p.active').next('.p');
  if ($target.length == 0)
    $target = $('.p:first');
    
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $target.offset().top
  }, 'slow');

  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $target.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.p {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
}
.p1 {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
.p2 {
  background-color: #E91E63;
}
.p3 {
  background-color: #01579B;
}

.admin {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p p1 active"></div>
<div class="p p2"></div>
<div class="p p3"></div>
<div class="admin">
  <button class="next">NEXT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If user scroll by hand first, then click button. Is this work to scroll to next div of current showing div ?

Comment: @thang no, for that you would need to monitor which element is currently shown when the scroll event happens, which you can achieve [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/519413)

Answer (score 7):

Use same class name for container.Start with first element.Each time click target the next `scroller` element

```js
var f = $('.p1');
var nxt = f;
$(".next").click(function() {

  if (nxt.next('.scroller').length > 0) {
    nxt = nxt.next('.scroller');
  } else {
    nxt = f;
  }
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: nxt.offset().top
    },
    'slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.p1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.p2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #E91E63;
}

.p3 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #01579B;
}

.admin {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p1 scroller">

</div>
<div class="p2 scroller">

</div>
<div class="p3 scroller">

</div>

<div class="admin">

  <button class="next">NEXT</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a basic version that moves forward and wraps around to the beginning when it reaches the last slide. We store `currSlide` outside of the loop and increment the number internally in the function.

For convenience, I added a `slide` class to each slide which allows me to:

- easily count the length of the slides
- condense the `CSS`

```js
let currSlide = 1;
const SLIDE_LENGTH = $('.slide').length;
$(".next").click(function() {
  currSlide = currSlide === SLIDE_LENGTH ? 1 : ++currSlide;
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(`.p${currSlide}`).offset().top
    },
    'slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Less repetition */
.slide {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
}

.p1 {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.p2 {
  background-color: #E91E63;
}

.p3 {
  background-color: #01579B;
}

.admin {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide p1"></div>
<div class="slide p2"></div>
<div class="slide p3"></div>

<div class="admin">
  <button class="next">NEXT</button>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjf1uyqo/1/)

**Bonus edit:**

In case you're interested in adding a previous button at some point…

```js
let currSlide = 1;
const SLIDE_LENGTH = $('.slide').length;

function moveSlide() {
  currSlide = $(this).hasClass("next") ? ++currSlide : --currSlide;
  if (currSlide < 1) {
    currSlide = SLIDE_LENGTH;
  }
  if (currSlide > SLIDE_LENGTH) {
    currSlide = 1;
  }
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(`.p${currSlide}`).offset().top
    },
    'slow');
}

$(".prev, .next").on("click", moveSlide);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Less repetition */

.slide {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
}

.p1 {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.p2 {
  background-color: #E91E63;
}

.p3 {
  background-color: #01579B;
}

.admin {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide p1"></div>
<div class="slide p2"></div>
<div class="slide p3"></div>

<div class="admin">
  <button class="prev">PREVIOUS</button>
  <button class="next">NEXT</button>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjf1uyqo/3/)

Comment: @freedomn-m Done.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question asks "How-to in Javascript", I will answer the question in a few lines of vanilla JS:

```
var p = 1;
const container = document.getElementById('container');
var nextPage = function() {
  var topPos = document.getElementsByClassName('page')[p++].offsetTop;
  container.scrollTo({top: topPos, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

in the above example, `page` is the class name you assign to your divs you want to scroll to, such as:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="page p1"></div>
  <div class="page p2"></div>
  <div class="page p3"></div>
</div>
```

Since you want to scroll the entire browser window, you just replace

```
container.scrollTo({top: topPos, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

with

```
window.scrollTo({top: topPos, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

like so:

```
var p = 1;
var nextPage = function() {
  var topPos = document.getElementsByClassName('page')[p++].offsetTop;
  window.scrollTo({top: topPos, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

You can subtract or add the number of pixels you want to offset the `topPos` if it's not in the right position